# Identifying all prime numbers less than 200

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Below is the question I am confused on. I will provide my logic to my solution also.

> In order to identify all the prime numbers less than 200, a person writes each number from 1 to 200, and eliminates all the multiples of 2, then all the multiples of 3. To complete this task, the person will have to eliminate the multiples of which additional numbers?
>
> A. 5, 7, 9,  11
>
> B. 7, 9, 11, 13
>
> C. 5, 7, 11, 13
>
> D. 7, 11, 13, 17

I eliminated answer choices A and B, since all multiples of 9, will ALSO be multiples of 3. So the person does not have to repeat the process over. I also eliminated answer choice C, since all multiples of 10, are also multiples of 5, which are also multiples of 2 (i.e. 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 etc.) Again, the person would not need to repeat the process over. So I chose answer D. However, the correct answer is C.

Comment: With D how do you eliminate 25?

Comment: Lord Shark the Unknown,
25 is not a prime number. ( 5 x 5 = 25).

Comment: Exactly, that is why it has to be eliminated!

Answer (score 8):

By always eliminating multiples of numbers you can guarantee that you only have to remove multiples of prime numbers (as you noted, you have already removed all multiples of 9 by removing all multiples of 3).  So the remaining issue is how large a prime number you have to reach before you've eliminated all the possible composite numbers.

Any composite (non-prime) number must have at least two factors, neither of which is one, e.g. $169 = 13 \times 13$, and those factors must be either equal, or one is larger than the other.  These numbers will always be eliminated when we remove the multiples of the smaller factor (e.g. $161 = 7 \times 23$ will be eliminated when we remove multiples of $7$ and so is gone when we reach multiples of $23$).

So, we can always stop when we reach the largest prime number smaller than the square root of the limit -- in this case, when we reach the largest prime number smaller than $\sqrt{200}$.  (The square root, say $a$ has the property that $a\times a = 200$ so any other combination of factors must have one larger, one smaller).

$13\times 13 = 169 < 200$ and $17\times 17 = 289 > 200$, so we don't need to check as far as $17$ and D cannot be the answer, which leaves C.

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is a bit "in reverse" when you are thinking about the 10. When you employed 2, the 10 & all of its multiples 20, 30, 40, et. al. were indeed eliminated. Note here that 25 was skipped. The fact that 5 is a factor of 10 makes no difference as that 5 never gets used. When actually using this method, its no problem at all to determine what number to use next: it's simply the next higher number not already marked out.

Answer (score 1):

Doing the sieve with the primes in order, the first nontrivial multiple of $p$ to eliminate is $p^2$.

If $p$ is an odd prime, then $2p$ should have already been eliminated when you were crossing off the multiples of $2$. But $p^2$ is odd, not even, so it shouldn't have been eliminated at a prior step. Likewise, if $p$ is a prime greater than $3$, then you don't need to cross $2p$ and $3p$ off again because they should have already been crossed off.

Let's see what happens with D. You might forget to cross off $35$ if you skip ahead to $49$. And then at the end of the process you might come to the absurd conclusion that both $5$ and $25$, and possibly $35$ and $105$, are also prime, which is of course incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

If $n>1$ and $n$ is not prime then $n=ab$ with $a>1$ and $b>1$ and it cannot be true that both $a$ and $b$ are $>\sqrt n.$ So one of $a,b$ is $\leq  \sqrt n$, and will have  a prime divisor that is also  $\leq \sqrt n.$

So if $1<n\leq 200$ and $n$ is not prime then $n$  is divisible by  a prime $p\leq \sqrt n\leq \sqrt {200}\;.$ The largest prime not exceeding  $\sqrt {200}\;$ is $13.$

You might also notice that the prime $5$ is not in choice D.  Using D would not eliminate $25$ or $125$ from the list of primes.

This method of finding primes is called the Sieve of Erastosthenes.